# What do these symbols mean in the RFC docs regarding grammars?

Tags: syntax, grammar, rfc, bnf

[Here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616) are the examples:

```
     Transfer-Encoding       = "Transfer-Encoding" ":" 1#transfer-coding
     Upgrade        = "Upgrade" ":" 1#product
     Server         = "Server" ":" 1*( product | comment )
     delta-seconds  = 1*DIGIT
     Via =  "Via" ":" 1#( received-protocol received-by [ comment ] )
     chunk-extension= *( ";" chunk-ext-name [ "=" chunk-ext-val ] )
     http_URL = "http:" "//" host [ ":" port ] [ abs_path [ "?" query ]]
     date3        = month SP ( 2DIGIT | ( SP 1DIGIT ))
```

Questions are:

1. What is the `1#transfer-coding` (the `1#` regarding the rule transfer-coding)? Same with `1#product`.
2. What does 1 times x mean, as in `1*( product | comment )`? Or `1*DIGIT`.
3. What do the brackets mean, as in `[ comment ]`? The parens `(...)` group it all, but what about the `[...]`?
4. What does the `*(...)` mean, as in `*( ";" chunk-ext-name [ "=" chunk-ext-val ] )`?
5. What do the nested square brackets mean, as in `[ abs_path [ "?" query ]]`? Nested optional values? It doesn't make sense.
6. What does 2DIGIT and 1DIGIT mean, where do those come from / get defined?

I may have missed where these are defined, but knowing these would help clarify how to parse the grammar definitions they use in the RFCs.

I get the rest of the grammar notation, juts not these few remaining pieces.

**Update**: Looks like [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5234#section-3.8) is a good start.

> Square brackets enclose an optional element sequence:
>
> ```
>     [foo bar]
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
>     *1(foo bar).
> ```
>
> Specific Repetition:  nRule
>
> A rule of the form:
>
> ```
>     <n>element
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
>     <n>*<n>element
> ```
>
> That is, exactly <n> occurrences of <element>.  Thus, 2DIGIT is a
> 2-digit number, and 3ALPHA is a string of three alphabetic
> characters.
>
> Variable Repetition:  *Rule
>
> The operator "*" preceding an element indicates repetition.  The full
> form is:
>
> ```
>     <a>*<b>element
> ```
>
> where <a> and <b> are optional decimal values, indicating at least
> <a> and at most <b> occurrences of the element.
>
> Default values are 0 and infinity so that *<element> allows any
> number, including zero; 1*<element> requires at least one;
> 3*3<element> allows exactly 3; and 1*2<element> allows one or two.

But what I'm still missing is what the `#` means?

**Update 2**: [Found it](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) I think!

> #RULE:  LISTS
>
> ```
>       A construct "#" is defined, similar to "*", as follows:
>
>                           <l>#<m>element
>
>  indicating at least <l> and at most <m> elements, each  separated
>  by  one  or more commas (","). This makes the usual form of lists
>  very easy; a rule such as '(element *("," element))' can be shown
>  as  "1#element".
> ```

Also, what do these mean?

- 1*2DIGIT
- 2*4DIGIT

Comment: Is there any actual question left here or is this just a record of your incremental reading of the RFC text?

Comment: What does `1*2DIGIT` mean? Is it one or more 2DIGIT, or 1 to 2 DIGIT? Mostly just a record, for others I guess. Definitely wasn't easy to find. If it's one or more 2DIGIT, then 11223344? Or what? Same with year for `2*4DIGIT`? How about `1*8(...)` is that one _or_ 8, or one _to_ 8 things?

Comment: But you quote the answer: "`<a>*<b>element` where `<a>` and `<b>` are optional decimal values, indicating **at least** `<a>` and **at most** `<b>` occurrences of the element." So at least 1 and at most 8 === from one to eight, inclusive.

Comment: Also, you really didn't need to look so far afield. The second chapter of RFC 2616 is entitled [2 Notational Conventions and Generic Grammar](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-2.1) and describes all of those syntax conventions. However, if you want the current standard, you should look at [RFC-7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230), not RFC-2616, which uses ABNF as defined in [RFC-5234](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5234)